# Spring Kafka : Subscribe to a new Topic Pattern during Runtime

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using the annotation @KafkaListener to consume topics in my application. I need to change the topic pattern at runtime in an already running consumer so that new topics that match the new pattern can be consumed.

I tried the below code, but it still consumes the topics matching the old topic pattern. Here, I have set the "old-topic-pattern" at application start-up. Then, I'm updating the pattern to "new-topic-pattern" every 10 seconds using a Spring @Scheduler.

```
Class "KafkaTopicPatternConfig.java":

@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicPatternConfig {

  @Bean
  public String kafkaTopicPattern(Environment env) {
    logger.info("Getting kafka topic pattern");
    String kafkaTopicPattern = "old-topic-pattern";
    return kafkaTopicPattern;
  }
}



Class "Consumer.java":

@Component
public class Consumer implements ConsumerSeekAware{

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("kafkaTopicPattern")
  private String kafkaTopicPattern;


  @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "#{kafkaTopicPattern}", id = "s4federatorConsumer")
  public void processMessage(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partitionId) {

        //do something with the consumed message

  }


  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000, initialDelay = 15000)
  public void refreshKafkaTopics() {
    logger.info("Inside scheduler to refresh kafka topics");
    this.kafkaTopicPattern = "new-topic-pattern";
    this.kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("s4federatorConsumer").stop();
    this.kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("s4federatorConsumer").start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help on this? Is it possible to change the Kafka Topic Pattern at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting kafkaTopicPattern as -

```
@Qualifier("kafkaTopicPattern")
private String kafkaTopicPattern;
```

I see you are updating the pattern like -

```
this.kafkaTopicPattern = "new-topic-pattern";
```

But the original value for "kafkaTopicPattern" which is injected in listener wont be refreshed by this if these 2 are in different instance objects. So you will have to make sure that the listener objects are refreshed with the new pattern.

Comment: The value of "kafkaTopicPattern" which is being injected is actually getting refreshed by this code. I tried to print the value inside the "processMessage" method, and I'm getting the old and new value of "kafkaTopicPattern". But the Kafka consumer upon restarting, is still not consuming the old pattern although the value of "kafkaTopicPattern" has been updated to new pattern.